# How to add script tags to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, atom-editor

[image]

Here in the image you see the code is greyed out.  Before I put in the `<script>` tag everything was not greyed out.  Once I put in the tag is greys out the rest of the code.  I might be missing a file needed to run the script tags?

I have been working with code for a while, but I am still a little stuck on how to get the code set up.  I am wanting to use html/css and JavaScript to make a couple websites.  I am not sure how to set everything up to make it work.  I also am using github, and trying to figure out how to use github-pages.

Comment: Maybe it's your text editor that just doesn't understand `<script/>` tags and/or renders them that way?  Have you tried running the code?  What are the results?

Comment: I've often seen this issue with people using Atom. Not sure how to fix. Try changing up your formatter, and/or removing the `type` attribute.

Comment: do you have a </html> tag at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Atom Code Editor. Why is my code not in color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383972/atom-code-editor-why-is-my-code-not-in-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that works:

1. Just close the file being edited
2. Click "File->Reopen Last Item" to re-open it

This is an issue with Atom, it does not detect the  tag when it auto completes, it works fine in VSCode, so it's not really a problem with your code, it's the IDE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9TYo.png)

Answer (score 1):

As i recognize, the Atom text editor makes this error.

The best solution i tried:

IN ATOM TEXT EDITOR
Windows:
Ctrl + ,
MAC:
Cmd + ,

In settings:

```
1. Scroll to the bottom,
2. Uncheck "Use Tree Sitter Parsers",
3. Restart Atom IDE.
```

That works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, but it seems no fix have been done yet, you can report your case here, I guess: [HTML Syntax Colour Bug](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13294)

But you may have solution in that StackOverflow subject, if so, it would be a duplicate: [Atom Code Editor. Why is my code not in color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383972/atom-code-editor-why-is-my-code-not-in-color)