# Why is my code not colorized in Atom Editor and acts like broken?

Tags: atom-editor

I am new to Atom and I've come across a problem. Any HTML code that is pasted or snippet isn't colorized in the editor. It doesn't show any effects when I open the file in a web browser as well. It acts like those codes aren't saved in the file.

I checked the language and it indeed is HTML (Since atom detects it from the file extension). I checked if my language package (language-html) is installed, and it certainly is.

[image: Screenshot showing uncolorised code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Atom Code Editor. Why is my code not in color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383972/atom-code-editor-why-is-my-code-not-in-color)

Comment: @ankitbeniwal No! I checked that page before posting this. It seems he only had problem with the language not being supported by the editor. Whereas in my case, My code is not being saved in the file (What I guessed). His problem was fixed by changing the language. Which I mentioned in the question.